# Required JSON file not returning all properties every time

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an API in a Node.js which requires a JSON file, and on some requests maps in content from it. Simple enough, and works perfectly for the first request.

On subsequent requests one of the properties is left off. This is obviously a stripped down version of the code, but is all I'm doing to get the content.

Essentially my JSON looks like:

```
{"sections": {
    "city": { 
       "title": "Seattle", 
       "info": "some info", 
       "tips": [ "tip 1", "tip 2" ] 
    }
  } 
}
```

and I require it:

```
var Content = require("content");

// some code

return req.status(200).json({ data: data, content: Content.sections.city });
```

The first request returns the whole content object. Every request after that returns only title and info, but not tips.

**Edit** -- I'm a dummy. In the `//some code` section, I work with the tips and eventually call delete on this version of the object. Apparently passing by reference still hasn't sunken in.

Comment: No plausible explanation immediately ready: need an SSCCE.

Comment: Anyway, I *suspect* that *"something"* - which is *not shown* - is modifying `Content.sections.city`. In Node.js, `require` will [*cache*](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) the file once it loads it. So if something *modifies the object-loaded-and-cached-once* then that change persist for all future requests.

Comment: Yep, you're 100% right. Me, I am the idiot who's calling delete on the tips property about 10 lines up in my code.

Any way to avoid cacheing it, other than calling the require inside the function that's using the data?

Comment: Moving `require` into the function will not fix the caching problem (I added a link to the previous comment) as it is a feature/limitation internal to Node's require implementation. There are handy npm packages about like [read-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-json) and [jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile), etc.

Comment: Thanks :) At least I didn't spend 8 hours beating my head against it.

Comment: Alternatively, if the JSON never changes just don't modify the original object - create a [deep] clone first and then modify/return the clone; or otherwise build the result 'from scratch'. There are npms for that too :)